# Command to open network "connect" window?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, gui

I'm looking for a command that opens the network "connect" window.

[image]

It's commonly opened from the network icon in the notification tray, but it can also be opened through the Network and Sharing Center control panel by clicking "Connect or disconnect".

Comment: What is it you're *actually* trying to do? Just save on the effort of clicking that icon?

Comment: @Karan It's a long story, but we're hoping to create a workaround for problem that appears to have no solution and effects a large amount of machines in our organization.

Comment: So you're just looking to open that dialog window on command, not actually connect to a WiFi network?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Correct.

Comment: Are you allowed to use third-party utilities for this?

Comment: is **rundll32.exe van.dll,RunVAN** what you want?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Seems like that's what he wants to me. :)

Comment: @magicandre1981 impressive!  make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show this dialog via running this command:

```
rundll32.exe van.dll,RunVAN
```

from a command prompt or via the "Run dialog" (<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)